# How to render a cycles scene in luxrender?

Tags: rendering, luxrender-render-engine

I'm doing a project in cycles and I want to render it but its too slow on my CPU. So I want to render the scene in luxrender but without starting the project all over again.

Comment: You can recycle the geometry but as far as I know you will have to rebuild your materials from scratch. Just copy your scene with *Link Object Data* option and then start replacing materials one by one. You can select multiple objects that use the same material and press 'Ctrl+L' > *Link Materials* to make them use the same material

Answer (score 5):

Luxrender in version 1.6 (latest iteration) offers a basic material converter. Check out the release notes on the Luxrender Site here (scroll down to the last entry): http://www.luxrender.net/wiki/New_in_1-6

The button to convert all materials is in the render tab:

[image: convert all]

to convert elements individually, do a space bar search in the 3D viewport. Hit <kbd>Space</kbd> and enter 'convert' gives you these functions:

[image: spacebar menu]

Disclaimer: If this makes your renderings FASTER I'm not sure. It depends on the scene and the aim. But it gives you a quicker starting point.